# How to retrieve the id attribute of the root node of a xml using XSL?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt

How to retrive the id attribute of the root node of a xml using XSL?

Comment: An example of the XML input, the expected behavior, and what you've tried, would be a great inducement for people to help you.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and a complete solution.

Comment: When you say "the id attribute" do you mean an attribute named "id"? (as opposed to an attribute declared to be of type ID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to retrive the id attribute of the
>   root node of a xml using XSL?

You mean ... of the *top element*. **[The root node](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#root-node) is not an element and cannot have attributes**.

This simple XPath expression selects the `id` attribute of the top element of any XML document:

```
/*/@id
```

In XSLT, one will use:

```
<xsl:variable name="vsomeName" select="/*/@id"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/*/@id"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*/@id"/>
```

Comment: +1. Note that in the XML spec, the term for the top element is "root or document element", and in XDM it appears to be "document element". However XSLT 2.0 spec editor Michael Kay prefers "outermost element" as it is less easily confused with its parent, the "document node".

Comment: @LarsH: I always use the term "top element" to make a clear distinction from the *root* node (the document node) as described in the W3C XPath 1.0 spec.: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#root-node

Comment: I understand, that makes sense. I wanted to let @user know that he/she would encounter different terms in the official specs, and why some serious XMLites don't use the official terms.